# Shortening URL GET options

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

I have a catalog type of application with a bunch of different filtering options allowing users to limit results, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[1][]" value="4" /> Filter 1-4<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[1][]" value="5" /> Filter 1-5<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[1][]" value="6" /> Filter 1-6<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[1][]" value="7" /> Filter 1-7<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[1][]" value="8" /> Filter 1-8<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[1][]" value="9" /> Filter 1-9<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="filters[2][]" value="10" /> Filter 2-10<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[2][]" value="11" /> Filter 2-11<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[2][]" value="12" /> Filter 2-12<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[2][]" value="13" /> Filter 2-13<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="filters[misc][]" value="1" /> Filter Misc-1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[misc][]" value="test" /> Filter Misc-test<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[misc][]" value="2" /> Filter Misc-2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[misc][]" value="3" /> Filter Misc-3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[misc][]" value="4" /> Filter Misc-4<br />

<select name="select">
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="1">Filter Select-1</option>
<option value="2">Filter Select-2</option>
<option value="3">Filter Select-3</option>
</select>
```

There are quite a few options like this and the selection might even grow bigger over time. I'm wondering if there is any way to compact these options when sending them to the url, so that I don't end up with an extremely long and unreadable address.

The only thing I can think of is to save every possible combination into a database ahead of time, then reference the ID... But that's probably not realistic considering the vast number of possible combinations. Is there a better alternative?

I'm after something like `example.com?filters=something_relatively_short_and_simple` if at all possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create code, that will save your list of search parameters (as JSON) in DB table (or maybe cache) and give you back an token (based on user's ID and then ID of newly created entry in `Queries` table).

Then you can reproduce the search query by calling `http://who.cares/?token=0acb087454d65ca63`

The table will be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Queries (
  `query_id`           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  `account_id`         BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `token`              CHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
  `created_on`         INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `used_on`            INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  `parameters`         TEXT,

  KEY (`account_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`token`),
  KEY (`used_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#### Update:

If those queries come from a public site (instead of some backend CMS/CRM, as I assumed), then it would be better to remove the `account_id` part and instead generate the `hash` from the JSON of the user's query parameters.

Comment: So this solution would save every possible combination, but only as requested (instead of doing it all ahead of time), is that right?

Comment: It would just save any combination that your user has made.

Comment: @mistermartin well, you can also ditch the `account` part and instead make the hash from the JSON of the user's query (that would work better, if it is not a backend system, as I originally assumed).